# How can I disable Quick Chat in Among Us on the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, among-us

It looks like the Switch version of Among Us had a update called Quick Chat; a mode that lets you select preset phrases to chat. However, I've attached a USB keyboard to my Switch, so I can chat normally fairly quickly. I see an option for "Chat Mode" in the settings, that's set to "Quick Chat", but it's grayed out, and I can't even move the cursor to it. Is there something I need to change in my Switch account to get full chat access?

Comment: Did you set your age to below 18? If your age is below 18 you're not able to use regular chat and can only use Quick Chat.

Comment: My nintendo account's date of birth is set correctly (I'm 29). I tried reinstalling the game, but it didn't ask for my age.

Comment: Well then I'm not sure. I play on mobile and PC so I'm not sure if it's a switch problem or if it's just a problem on your end. There is a bug fix patch coming sometime soon on Switch so that might fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "disable" Quick Chat in Among Us on the Nintendo Switch, you must have your age to upper 18.

---

> Lying about your age is common to all kids that want extra features.

---

#### Changing your age

This is how to change your name according to [ESRB Ratings](https://esrb.com/tools-for-parents/nintendo-switch):
(Press "Home" on your console before following these steps)

- Tap "Console Settings"
- Tap "Restriction Level"
- Select the Appropriate Age for Your Child

**The third step will not work unless you are the admin/caregiver of your own Switch.**

---

#### Conclusion

Open "Among Us". The age should link to Among Us and change your age/birthdate. Enjoy the disabled Quick Chat.

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled my son's "Quick chat" to "Free and quick chat".

I first deleted his saved data. Then, I rebooted the game back up, clicked on "Sign in" (It probably signed in automatically as I was not asked for any login details), then went to the chat options. I clicked on data > "Quick chat" and it changed to "Free chat and quick chat". After I backed out, I tried to enter a local game and the full keyboard appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your logged in first then go to settings to change the chat option.